# Reveal.js with highcharts

Tags: highcharts, reveal.js

I'm using reveal.js (http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/) together with Highcharts JS but i have problems with tooltips position. For example, if i use a line with the months on the x axis, when i put the mouse over the point in january the tooltip its ok, but when i put the mouse over december the tooltip shows me the october data. The tooltip for each month is displaced more and more.

You can see http://lideria.net/presentacion/index1.php to see the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be problem with Highcharts which us already reported [here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1753). Also there is suggested `workaround`: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/BD3R7/

Comment: That's only works for the first chart, the next have the same problems.

Comment: It should work the same way for all charts. If not, feel free to add comment under ticket - but first recreate issue on jsFiddle.

Comment: I don't see how to recreate reveal slide in a fiddle.

Comment: Recreate issue without reveal.js - as you can see, I connected issue with standalone version of Highcharts.

Comment: Without Reveal.js I don't have any problems or as long as I have only one chart for all reveal slide it's works too. But 2 charts on the same slide or on different slides cause tooltip wrong position for the second.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. Without live demo, I can't debug this and I can't really help you. jsFiddle is just place where you can write code like html/js (like any of our examples).

Answer (score 1):

`reveal.js` autoscales the viewport with a css zoom tag.  If you inspect `class="slides"` div, you'll see something like this:

```
<div class="slides" style="width: 960px; height: 700px; zoom: 0.8331428571428572;">
```

Here the content (the chart) is scaled 80% of normal size and Highcharts loses it's ability to calculate positions properly if the chart is scaled outside of its control.

With that knowledge, a [quick stack overflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19622659/prevent-reveal-js-to-zoom) talks about the ability to force 'reveal.js` [to not auto-scale content](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#presentation-size).

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if i enable not auto-scale content, the content, including the chart don't appear correctly when i change of device, i mean that i will lose the responsive capability. Is there any way to do without lose the responsive capability ?

Comment: @estebanjuela, couple ideas come to mind: 1.) hook the `slidechanged` event (https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#slide-changed-event) and redraw the chart to the actual dimensions of the viewport.  2.) Use the tooltips `positioner` function (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.positioner) to fudge the position based on the current zoom.  Neither of these options seem very pleasant, though.  Hopefully, someone else comes along with better ideas!

Answer (score 0):

You must overwrite the `normalize` of the `H.Pointer.prototype` (referenced [WRAPPING UP A PLUGIN](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts)). Add the following code to document.ready function (maybe somewhere else works, I guess). The reasons are:

1. reveal.js has separate ways when zoom>1 and zoom<1, e.g., `zoom:1.25` and `transform:scale(0.75)`.
2. So, when a section has several charts and zoom>1, must adjust `e.chartX` by `e.pageX`.

   ```
   (function (H) {
       H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'normalize', function (proceed, e) {
           var e = proceed.call(this,e);
           var zoom = Reveal.getScale();
           if(zoom>1) {
           var positionX = e.pageX - e.chartX;
           var positionY = e.pageY - e.chartY;
           e.chartX = Math.round((e.pageX - positionX*zoom)/zoom);
           e.chartY = Math.round((e.pageY - positionY*zoom)/zoom); 
           } else {
             e.chartX = Math.round(e.chartX/zoom);
             e.chartY = Math.round(e.chartY/zoom);
           }
         return e;
       });
   }(Highcharts));
   ```